# How can I make the "CacheListenerAdapter" work in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, geode

I have set up apache geode and I am using `Pivotal.Gemfire.dll` to set up the cache listener by extending `CacheListenerAdapter`.

Problem is, the below never fires when listening to the region with the correct key:

```
    public override void AfterCreate(EntryEvent<TKey, TVal> ev)
    {
        //code
    }
```

This does, however, work in a desktop application (Console.app/WinForms) but not in web application (MVC/WebForms)

If someone could help me or point me to the correct documentation page, I would really appreciate, it's been 3 days since I'm trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a version of GemFire Native Client less than 10.0.0 then you are likely running into an issue with AppDomain in ASP.NET. While many AppDomain issues are mitigated in 9.x some are just not possible to address in that version. Updating to the latest 10.x should address your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try version 10, and get back here.